# WordPress menu with custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, menus

I'm looking for a scalable, best-practice way to do the following:

I need a menu to have a link to the homepage, a standard page, and a variable number of custom post type archives. Each archive must also have one standard sub-page and a category page with all the posts with a specific custom taxonomy. So the menu would look like this:

```
 Home
 About
 Artist 1 Archive
      About Artist 1
      Custom Taxonomy
 Artist 2 Archive
      About Artist 2
      Custom Taxonomy
```

And so on for all other artists.

Currently, I'm using WordPress's built-in archives for the custom post types, so they're not showing up in my menu--but I'm not adverse to just using a custom url (e.g., /artist-1/). What I'm having difficulty with is how to create the archives for the custom taxonomy. Is there a way I can set up a page template and somehow use `get_query_var()` to get the post type? Or is there a more natural way to do this?

Finally, I also have to redirect the URL; the custom taxonomy's category will be `yes`, but I need to change it to be accessed at `portfolio`.

Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe for the next time, create a question for each topic ;)

**1) Menu Item for Custom Post Type archive**

I don't have an automated solution here. But in my opionion it should be possible to create a similar widget inside the Menu Admin Page to display all Posttypes with an archive and generate a link to it which you than can drag&drop to your desired menu.

**2) Post Template for Custom Taxonomy**

If you display a term of a custom taxonomy, the default `archive.php` template is used. You could use some conditional statements to display content based on the taxonomy or the post type e.g. `if(is_tax('YOUR_TAX') || is_post_type_archive('YOUR_POSTTYPE'))`. It should also be possible to use `archive-{tax}.php` for a static template file, but haven't tested it with the post type archives.

**3) Permalink for Custom Taxonomy**

During registration, you could set the rewrite parameter. So you could basically generate something like this:

```
http://yourblog.tld/parent/cpt/<post>    
http://yourblog.tld/parent/cpt/taxonomy/<post>
```

To do this, you have to register your custom post type first with a special `rewrite` parameter. Than you register a new taxonomy object with `register_taxonomy_for_object_type` for your custom post type **before** you register your custom taxonomy. As described by Jan Fabry in a answer here on SE, this is necessary for the correct order of the generated rewrite rules.

**Custom Post Type**

```
$args = array(
    // your arguments
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'parent/cpt', 'with_front' => false)
);

register_post_type('YOUR_POSTTYPE', $args);
register_taxonomy_for_object_type('YOUR_TAXONOMY', 'YOUR_POSTTYPE');
```

**Custom Taxonomy**

```
$args = array(
   // your arguments
   'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'parent/cpt/taxonomy', 'with_front' => false)
)

register_taxonomy('YOUR_TAXONOMY', array(), $args);
```